# How To Hide Joomla Easysocial Group "files" Delete Option For Group Members?

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, joomla-extensions

How do I protect easysocial group file's from groups members against delete action. Only group admin or super admin should be able to delete files, not a joining group member.

[image]

how remove this red lined buttons for groups members

Answer (score 0):

I have not work with easysocial ever but I think it's simple.

At first check at backend. If no configuration for it then you have to change code at this view files. Pick the user type. If the logged user type is super admin or group admin, then the delete button will appear. Simple "if" condition.

It would be better to check user type at controller function of it too.